# Removing rows and columns which contain all NaN rows in a matrix

Tags: r

I have data in the format of

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]    2    NaN    7 
[2,]    NaN  NaN    NaN 
[3,]    3    NaN    2
```

I want to remove row 2 and column 2. when I tried

```
mat <- mat[complete.cases(mat)]
```

it deletes all cases (since none of them are complete).

Is there a simple way to do this, besides replacing the NaN with zeros and doing some math on zero sum columns, and then the same for rows?

Comment: You could try `mat[is.nan(mat)] <- 0` and then use `rowSums`, `colSums(mat)`, but it also has `na.rm=TRUE` option which will give the same result.  If you need to exclude all `NaN` rows, `mat[rowSums(!is.nan(mat))>0,]`, similary do that do that for columns `mat[,colSums(!is.nan(mat))>0]`

Comment: Also when i use mat <- mat[is.nan(mat)], I get a vector instead of a matrix back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
mat[rowSums(!is.nan(mat))>0,]
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2  NaN    7
#[2,]    3  NaN    2

 mat[,colSums(!is.nan(mat))>0]
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    2    7
 #[2,]  NaN  NaN
 #[3,]    3    2
```

when combined

```
mat[rowSums(!is.nan(mat))>0,colSums(!is.nan(mat))>0]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    7
#[2,]    3    2
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(c(2, NaN, 3, NaN, NaN, NaN, 7, NaN, 2), ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

mat <- mat[-2,-2]

Answer (score 0):

In this case your NaN's are symmetrically placed leaving you with a nice 2 x 2 residual matrix. This might not always be the case.

What you need to do really takes two moves(locate non-NaN's, then rebuild new matrix) but can be combined into a reasonable one-liner.

```
newMat <- matrix( mat[!is.na(mat)], nrow=2 ,  ncol=2)
```

Note that we are building our new matrix column-wise from the resulting vector when we index the NaN's.  There is no getting around the fact we are gonna have to build a second matrix from scratch.  Our new matrix will not 'fall' into place via gravity.

Comment: I guess the only way to automatically detect the number of new rows and columns is to do basically what @akrun mentioned though